# This in object methods

Tags: javascript

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
  let f = this;
console.log(this);
    
  return function(...args) {
     console.log(this);
     setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, args), ms);
  }
};

let user = {
  name: "John",
  sayHi() {
    alert(this.name);
  }
}

user.sayHi = user.sayHi.defer(1000);
user.sayHi();
```

Hi! Here is the gist of this code: we must add to the prototype of all functions the method defer(ms), that returns a wrapper, delaying the call by ms milliseconds. It must work like this:

```
`function f(a, b) {
  alert( a + b );
}

f.defer(1000)(1, 2); // shows 3 after 1 second`
```

As it should be also work fine for object's methods, in this code **this** explicitly assigned to **let f**.
My question is about **this**. Why in first console.log **this** it's method sayHi, and in second - it's object user? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Because the first log is executed when `user.sayHi.defer` function is called, here the context is `user.sayHi`. The second log is executed when `user.sayHi()` is called, here the context is `user`.